# Angular 6 how to make one or two buttons visible

Tags: angular

I have 2 buttons on dialog, and I have to use this dialog in 2 cases, for new and for edit form. But in edit form case those 2 buttons should be visible, and in new case form only save button should be visible

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <div class="col-lg">
    <button class="simple-btn" (click)="delete()" mat-button>Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <button type="button" class="simple-btn" (click)="save()" mat-button>Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Depending on how you implement your dialog, you could check if your `@Input()` 
 has `value` or if it's `null`. When the component is initialized via `ngOnInit` then set a boolean variable to `true` or `false`

Comment: My question is how to make delete button invisible for new case, and visible for edit case

Comment: How does your component determine whether it's new or edit? Use that to determine whether to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add variable for each case and use ngIf on your button or on the div over. In your component you would need to set `new` and `edit` or they would need to come from an `Input` since you are talking about dialog.

In your component, you would need something like this:

```
@Input edit: boolean; // Coming from parent saying if you are in edit mode
```

or using some logic to assign edit:

```
if(logic to know if im editing) {
    edit = true or false
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <div class="col-lg" *ngIf="edit">
    <button class="simple-btn" (click)="delete()" mat-button>Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <button type="button" class="simple-btn" (click)="save()" mat-button>Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I added both *ngIf both buttons disappeared but when I add only on delete button it is invisible in both cases. I am beginner in angular and that is still new for me, and I am not sure where and what to add. So is it possible to add only something for edit, and what could it be.

Comment: Well if you want only one input saying you are in edit mode, you can always remove the ngIf on the save button and keep it on the delete button

Comment: @vvv.mmmmm Then you're doing something wrong with your `*ngIf` or the code used to determine its value. Can you add both of those things to the question along with your explanation from your comment?